# how can i add javascript files into angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

i have got a template works fine on visual studio , but when i tried to use it on my angular project i don't know why the javascript code doesn't work , i filled the app.component.html with the html code and i imported the css code . i installed bootstrap and font-awesome. the only problem i got is i don't know how to add javascript code into my project (angular 13 btw).

```
(function ($) {
"use strict";

// Spinner
var spinner = function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        if ($('#spinner').length > 0) {
            $('#spinner').removeClass('show');
        }
    }, 1);
};
spinner();
```

Comment: Adding JavaScript code is not considered a good practice but it's totally possible, TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript so JavaScript code just works. You should tell us also the problem you're having

Comment: The ideal angular practice is to avoid using jquery in your component. You can, however, create a js file and put it in angular.json. You can also use the npm package to create a spinner.

Comment: Add a link to the file in you index.html page like you would normally. A better solution would be to use angular to do this, using a component and service. Angular has ngClass or Renderer2 to add / remove the class.

Comment: would you please take a look into the repository on github https://github.com/benbrahi/javascript-issue.git

Comment: i tried to add the js files into the assets directory . i also tried to add the link of the js file in the angular.json . but still no results

Comment: the problem i am having is that the project runs fine but it doesn't show me anything on the browser all i can see is a blank page with a researching logo on the middle

Comment: jayme i did add the link of the js file to the index.html  but i still have the same problem

Comment: @BADR_Ah - remove the "assets/js/javascript.component.js" from angular.json if you are importing it in your index.html. Also the links in your index.html page need to be updated, currently they are not in your template and are looking for a path 'bootstrap-template-ihm-gestion/'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use javascript in my angular project.
Try to import javascript in **your-project/src/index.html** inside the body tag.

```
 <body>
    <app-root id="app-root"></app-root>
    <script> </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I think this works on angular 7 . But i have the 13 version . I tried it but stiil nothing . Would you mind to check my repository https://github.com/benbrahi/javascript-issue.git

Comment: I'm running your code here. I need to understand what do yo want to do. Maybe we can solve this using ts. Explain to me what you need to do, please.

Comment: I wanna run this template on angular https://themewagon.com/themes/free-bootstrap-5-html5-business-startup-website-template-startup/